# Why hasn't the EU approved Russia's COVID vaccine yet?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, covid-19, vaccine

Hungary started to administer the Russain-developed Sputnik V COVID-19 vaccines recently while the EU did not authorize it yet (see e.g. https://www.euronews.com/2021/02/20/sputnik-v-why-hasn-t-the-eu-approved-russia-s-covid-vaccine-yet). According to the article, *"The EMA insists that Sputnik V has not even started the continuous review phase yet"*, while *"the Russian authorities "filed an application for registration" on January 19."*. It looks like at least there's a serious miscommunication here between the parties. I'd guess it can't be **that** hard to start this application (even if it's technically complicated, a few phone calls for tech help could solve the issue). Why is there no progress made on this issue? I mean the EU must be motivated to buy some more vaccines as only a tiny percentage of the population is vaccinated yet. The producer of the Sputnik vaccine should be also motivated to sell its ware (and sell before the market gets saturated).

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking why Russia hasn't filed an application for review? Or why the EU doesn't just approve the use of the vaccine without any review?

Comment: Russia has even lower Covid vaccination than the EU. https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/3927/production/_116913641_vaccine_rate_map_11feb-nc.png So why would they be in a hurry to export  to the EU?

Answer (score 2):

In a Feb 10 news release EMA [disagrees](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/news/clarification-sputnik-v-vaccine-eu-approval-process):

> The European Medicines Agency has to date not received an application for a rolling review or a marketing authorisation for the vaccine developed by the Gamaleya National Centre of Epidemiology and Microbiology in Russia, the Sputnik V vaccine (Gam-COVID-Vac), despite reports stating the opposite.

As of Feb 11, Russia has [even lower](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/3927/production/_116913641_vaccine_rate_map_11feb-nc.png) Covid-19 vaccination than the EU. So why would they be in a hurry to export to the EU, publicity stunts (like those with Hungary) aside? (Keep in mind that Hungary is very small market compared to the whole of the EU.)

Comment: I couldn't find data more recent than Feb 12 for Hungary (in English) but by then, [there were](https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20210212-hungary-to-start-covid-19-vaccinations-with-russia-s-sputnik-v-bypassing-eu-regulator) 2,800 doses of Sputnik used there... and 291,396 doses of Pfizer or Moderna. That's two orders of magnitude difference. (It's also true that Hungary ordered 600,000 Sputnik doses, but it remains to be seen when those will be delivered.)