# Why Global North countries collectively hate Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, media, sanctions

For me being unfamiliar with western propaganda/popular news agenda etc. it is not clear. It seems to be something everyone already knows and obvious.

Just to be clear, by Global North countries I mean governments, and by "hate" I mean policies and political processes.
By Russia I mean mostly the Russian folks.

If this question is not helpful to you, why?

To moderators: The primary purpose of this question is not to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It is a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes.

Comment: What do you base this on? I don't know anyone who hates the Russian people as a whole. Opinions were more divided on the Russian government until February 2022, now they are widely despised.

Comment: The various wars of aggression and numerous war crimes Russia recently committed might have something to do with it ...

Comment: @user47745 but you certainly know someone who hates Russia?

Comment: Of course there are many people who feels quite strongly about Russia's attitudes on the international stage. There are also some people who feel strongly about Russia's oppressive internal policies.

Comment: Global North, eh? When you start excluding the country with [the northernmost inhabited settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barneo?wprov=sfla1) from your definition of the Global North, maybe it's time to rethink the usefulness of the terminology.

Comment: If you went to a place like Egyptian jail, you'd be surprised how many rude people from all over the world exist and can collect in one big room, Russians being minority. People are mostly authoritarian and aggressive in countries like Sudan, Etheria, and they always invade other countries. They also sell their fellow citizens into slavery and do many other bad things rutinely

Comment: @meriton: "A plurality of Russians did not believe their country’s actions are responsible for Finland and Sweden’s applications to join NATO (49%)." https://globalaffairs.org/research/public-opinion-survey/do-russians-fear-west That doesn't mean others will hate them for that, but it begets at least a "rolls eyes" in the West.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. North and South Sudan have complicated relationship, but noone is the Congress has ever approved giving these countries billions of dollars to help kill each other

Comment: * Hate - intense hostility and aversion usually deriving from fear, anger, or sense of injury.

Comment: Simply *saying* that a question is asked in good faith doesn't make it asked in good faith, I'm afraid.

Comment: No, it's serious, it has quotes, and doesn't promote anything. Discrediting sanctions is not the sole purpose of asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Global North' benefits from what is sometimes called the [rules-based international order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_international_order). This means that borders are fixed unless they are changed by *genuine* mutual agreement, companies are mostly free to trade and invest with few *unfair* restrictions, etc. (Of course *unfair* would be in the eye of the beholder.) The 'West' like the status quo.

By contrast, Russia is a [revisionist power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revisionist_state). They want to overturn the status quo. When Russia questions the legitimacy of *some* former Soviet republics, at the core it questions the legitimacy of *all* of them, and also of the dissolution of the Warsaw Pact. Some of those countries are part of the EU and NATO these days.

As a very rough summary:

- In the 1980s, the Soviets were feared as a totalitarian superpower.
- In the early 1990s, the Russians were congratulated for overthrowing Communism. There was unspecific talk that they might join the EU or even NATO, some time in the future.
- In the late 1990s (the [Yeltzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Yeltsin) years). Russia was pitied for being ruled by a drunkard and controlled by organized criminals.
- Since the late 00s (the [2007 speech in Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Munich_speech_of_Vladimir_Putin) was a landmark), Russia has given up on joining the EU and NATO and instead decided to fight them. It took the EU and NATO a [very](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Schr%C3%B6der#Business_activities) [long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Orb%C3%A1n) time to realize that and fight back.

---

PS -- in this case, 'Global North' may be inappropriate. People used to talk about the [First, Second, and Third World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World) during the Cold War, and with a few changes that concept has become relevant again.

Comment: Are *any* of these concepts useful? "Global North" and "Global South" conflate geography with other factors of interest in an incredibly unclear and confusing manner; "West" and "East" have the same problem and play into clash of civilizations and Orientalist narratives; and "First World," "Second World" and "Third War" establish an explicit ordering of superiority and are based on inapplicable Cold War alignments. Perhaps it is time for people to actually explicitly specify what they think are the factors of interest and which countries fall into which groups for a given situation.

Comment: @Obie2.0, while the ordering has unfortunate implications, my point here is that the Cold War alignments *are* coming back. This time with China as the senior *Second World* power, a diminshed *Near Abroad* for Russia, and again with fights for influence and proxy conflicts in the rest of the world.

Answer (score 5):

The European Union has [published a FAQ](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/sanctions/restrictive-measures-against-russia-over-ukraine/) about their sanctions, which writes:

> Since March 2014, the EU has progressively imposed restrictive measures on Russia in response to:
>
> - the illegal annexation of Crimea
> - Russia’s war of aggression against Ukraine
> - the illegal annexation of Ukraine's Donetsk, Luhansk, Zaporizhzhia and Kherson regions
>
> The measures are designed to weaken Russia's economic base, depriving it of critical technologies and markets and significantly curtailing its ability to wage war.

They also [explain](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/sanctions/):

> Restrictive measures or 'sanctions' are an essential tool of the EU's Common Foreign and Security Policy (CFSP).
>
> Sanctions seek to bring about a change in the policy or conduct of those targeted, with a view to promoting the objectives of the CFSP. They can target:
>
> - governments of non-EU countries because of their policies
> - entities (companies) providing the means to conduct the targeted policies
> - groups or organisations such as terrorist groups
> - individuals supporting the targeted policies, involved in terrorist activities etc.
>
> They are developed in such a way as to minimise adverse consequences for those not responsible for the policies or actions leading to the adoption of sanctions. In particular, the EU works to minimise the effects on the local civilian population and on legitimate activities in or with the country concerned.

The objectives of the Common Foreign and Security Policy are defined in article 21 of the Treaty on European Union, which writes:

> 1. The Union's action on the international scene shall be guided by the principles which have inspired its own creation, development and enlargement, and which it seeks to advance in the wider world: democracy, the rule of law, the universality and indivisibility of human rights and fundamental freedoms, respect for human dignity, the principles of equality and solidarity, and respect for the
>    principles of the United Nations Charter and international law. [...]
> 2. The Union shall define and pursue common policies and actions, and shall work for a high degree of cooperation in all fields of international relations, in order to:
>    (a) safeguard its values, fundamental interests, security, independence and integrity;
>    (b) consolidate and support democracy, the rule of law, human rights and the principles of international law;
>    (c) preserve peace, prevent conflicts and strengthen international security, in accordance with the purposes and principles of the United Nations Charter, with the principles of the Helsinki Final Act and with the aims of the Charter of Paris, including those relating to external borders;
>    [...]

So no, the EU does not hate Russians. Rather, it uses coercive measures in an attempt to get Russia to halt its illegal aggression, and comply with the resolution the General Assembly of the United Nations adopted [with 141 vs 7 votes](https://news.un.org/en/story/2023/02/1133847), which, among other items:

> Reiterates its demand that the Russian Federation immediately, completely and unconditionally withdraw all of its military forces from the territory of Ukraine within its internationally recognized borders, and calls for a cessation of hostilities;

Comment: and how weakening Russia's economic base, depriving it of critical technologies and markets is meant to make them less aggressive? Usually it's the other way around

Comment: I seriously question the intent of sanctions against Russia, and 'hate" seems the only rational explanation for them. Not only weakening economy doesn't reduce aggression, but also proposed sanctions don't even weaken the economy.

Comment: So you are saying that the sanctions are simultaneously ineffective and so sweeping and powerful they must be motivated by hate? Isn't that view a little inconsistent ...? How can it be hate if Russia isn't hurt? How can Russia be hurt if the sanctions have no effect?

Comment: If hate were the motivation, why do EU sanctions [specifically](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/sanctions/restrictive-measures-against-russia-over-ukraine/) "target the financial, trade, energy, transport, technology and defence sectors", while leaving the remaining economy unaffected? The considerable restraint and selective targeting of these sanctions can not be explained by hate, only by compassion. But this compassion does not just extend to the people of Russia, but also to the people of Ukraine, and so the EU does not stand idly by while the former murder the latter ...

Comment: even if sanctions are good for Russian economy (so is annexation of Crimea), sanctions specifically target international trade and relationships and further isolate Russia, so I'm thinking it's not only compassion...

Answer (score 3):

On the lighter side, to adapt from Bush, "you forgot Hungary!" They love you.

On the more serious side, equating "hate of Russian folks" with dislike of Russia's foreign policy (to say nothing of their military ventures) is part and parcel of Russian propaganda.

---

This was said in a comment by the OP

> Russians don't care neither about invading other countries, nor about anything else. They are by design politically indifferent and mostly talk about food or express disapproval of those who don't align with them (this I believe is universal). Neither Russian government consists of some kind of evil uncivilized people.

Well, here's this poll for you, conducted in Russia in 2015 (when Pew could still operate there):

> [image]

Granted, there is the [added] subtilty here that people who care little about politics generally don't participate in such polling to begin with. You might even argue that even Russians who answer such polls don't obsess over that every day, but ultimately you're ignoring the focusing power that concentrated state media can achieve. Or concentrated political power, [for that matter](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russias-lower-house-approves-annexation-four-ukrainian-regions-2022-10-03):

> The lower house of Russia's parliament approved laws on Monday on annexing four occupied Ukrainian territories into Russia, following hastily organised votes that Ukraine and the West denounced as coercive and illegitimate.
>
> **No lawmakers in the State Duma voted against the resolutions**, which sought to formally incorporate Ukraine's Kherson, Donetsk, Luhansk and Zaporizhzhia regions into Russia.

Comment: But let's remember that even before February 2022, Russian people were somehow inferior. Even though they were first to come up with vaccine for COVID (Sputnik -V), this vaccine was never approved by any western country leading to refusing Russians tourist entry

Comment: @troya: FWTW https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/62694/why-hasnt-the-eu-approved-russias-covid-vaccine-yet

Comment: @troya, if you think that Russia invaded Ukraine only in 2022, there is part of the problem.

Comment: It seems true however that many Russians would rather forget about the ongoing war https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/sep/02/kremlins-propaganda-film-ukraine-war-plays-to-empty-cinemas

Answer (score 1):

At an "emotional" level, since we are talking about "hate", which is a sentiment, post-1989, Western-aligned countries did not "hate" Russia.  They were at worst fairly indifferent, being glad to have gotten rid of its precursor, the USSR.  It may come as a surprise, but many of us were quite happy to welcome back our long-lost cousins (to an extent).

Perhaps the West should have helped Russia more, a la Marshall Plan.  Didn't happen and too late now.

As time has gone by, Russia and the West have gotten steadily more antagonistic.

Consequently, the popular Western viewpoint of Russia has considerably slipped over time.  The reverse, continued benign indifference would be rather strange.

As to strident propaganda, no normal Western news channel would have a prime time anchor [fantasize about launching a Poseidon nuclear torpedo to radioactivize the UK with a huge tsunami](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hRz3qfWzqQ).  And keep his job.

p.s. IIRC you frequently ask about getting asylum in a Western country and not getting discriminated against. Can't say this kind of attitude would be conducive to much tolerance in most of our countries.  Just like someone asking asylum in Russia would not be very well received if they ranted about how much Russia hates their country of origin.

Comment: I never said anything about hate for western countries, neither does Russian propaganda if you have a chance to hear it in the west  (we here in Russia don't have access to western news channels as people would perceive them to be very offensive). And regarding the western sentiment being negative, this is a result of propaganda, which is paid by the capitalists. Before 1989 it was clear why they hated USSR (who threatened them directly) now not so much clear.

Answer (score 0):

The feeling is not hate. You do not hate say cold winter in a normal sense. It is about understanding which dangers there are obvious here and which actions are required  to take in order to be safe. Like joining Nato and the like.

Even if you see these views as propaganda, may be important to point out that this say propaganda is not focused on hate, just on safety. Sanctions touching the ordinary Russian citizens are all justified on assumptions that this should reduce the popularity of they dangerous dictator.

If Russia would manage to persuade these nations they are no more danger to them, it would not be any hate or sanctions remaining.